# Selenium how to not block the execution of tests if any of the tests fail

Tags: java, selenium

I run selenium test ti gives me

5 Steps (1 failed, 2 skipped, 2 passed)

how to how to  not block the execution of tests if any of the tests fail.

here is my code below

```
@When("^user enters username and email and password$")
public void user_enters_username_and_email_and_password() throws InterruptedException {

    for (User1 user:loadUserStepDfn.data){
        createUser.enterUsername(user.getUsername());
        createUser.enterEmail(user.getEmail());
        createUser.enterPassword(user.getPassword());


    if(!user.getUsermsg().isEmpty()) {
        Assert.assertEquals(createUser.getUsername_rqM(), user.getUsermsg());
        }

    if(!user.getEmailmsg().isEmpty()) {
            Assert.assertEquals(createUser.getEmail_rqM(), user.getEmailmsg());
        }
    if(!user.getPassmsg().isEmpty()) {
            Assert.assertEquals(createUser.getPassword_rqM(), user.getPassmsg());
        }


        createUser.clickOnCreate();
        createUser.clearAll();
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe soft assertions `org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert` will help you. Soft assertions are assertions that do not terminate the test when they fail but their results are included in the test execution report.

Comment: it doesn't work it re-explain my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436070/i-want-selenium-to-not-ignored-test-when-find-failed-test-case

Answer (score 0):

You should use SoftAssert for that, or you can try to do with try catch block like this:

```
 if (!user.getUsermsg().isEmpty()) {
     try {
         Assert.assertEquals(createUser.getUsername_rqM(), user.getUsermsg());
     } catch (AssertionError e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
 }

 if (!user.getEmailmsg().isEmpty()) {
     try {
         Assert.assertEquals(createUser.getEmail_rqM(), user.getEmailmsg());
     } catch (AssertionError e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
 }

 if (!user.getPassmsg().isEmpty()) {
     try {
         Assert.assertEquals(createUser.getEmail_rqM(), user.getEmailmsg());
     } catch (AssertionError e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
 }
```